# Android - Volley post parameters adding extra '&'

Tags: android, http, networking, android-volley

I am converting my application to use the Volley framework.

I have everything working as far as I can tell, when I make a webservice request using HttpClient, wireshark is showing my parameters as

> devicePrint=Android&mobileSaveUserId=false&__ResponseType=XML&appVersion=Android-3.2&__ResponseTypeVersion=1.0&userId=mbltest6&retrievePostedTransaction=falseHTTP/1.1
>   200 OK

This works perfectly, but when I use volley, my packet looks like this.

> devicePrint=Android&mobileSaveUserId=false&__ResponseType=XML&appVersion=Android-3.2&__ResponseTypeVersion=1.0&userid=mbltest6&retrievePostedTransaction=false&HTTP/1.1
>   200 OK

I moved them side by side and noticed the volley example (The bottom one) is appending an extra "&" which is causing my webservice to return "Username not found" even though it is clearly in there.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Or why it's happening?

EDIT: Upon further investigation into the base classes, when you set the parameters it always adds an extra "&" to the end of the string. Is this normal behavior for volley? Could this be whats causing my request to fail?

```
private byte[] encodeParameters(Map<String, String> params, String paramsEncoding) {
    StringBuilder encodedParams = new StringBuilder();

    try {
        Iterator uee = params.entrySet().iterator();

        while(uee.hasNext()) {
            java.util.Map.Entry entry = (java.util.Map.Entry)uee.next();
            encodedParams.append(URLEncoder.encode((String)entry.getKey(), paramsEncoding));
            encodedParams.append('=');
            encodedParams.append(URLEncoder.encode((String)entry.getValue(), paramsEncoding));
            encodedParams.append('&');
        }

        return encodedParams.toString().getBytes(paramsEncoding);
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException var6) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Encoding not supported: " + paramsEncoding, var6);
    }
}
```

My code is as follows:

```
public abstract class WebServiceRequest extends StringRequest {

private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = (1000 * 60);

private static final String RESPONSE_TYPE_KEY = "__ResponseType";
private static final String RESPONSE_TYPE_VERSION_KEY = "__ResponseTypeVersion";
private static final String APP_VERSION_KEY = "appVersion";
private static final String RETRIEVE_POSTED_KEY = "retrievePostedTransaction";

public boolean mRetrievePostedTransactions;
private Map<String, String> mParameters;

public WebServiceRequest(String url, Response.Listener<String> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(Method.POST, url, listener, errorListener);
    this.mParameters = new HashMap<>();
    setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            SOCKET_TIMEOUT,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT
    ));
}


public abstract void setParams(Map<String,String> params);


@Override
protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
    setCommonParameters(mParameters);
    setParams(mParameters);
    return mParameters;
}

private Map<String, String> setCommonParameters (Map<String,String> params) {
    params.put( APP_VERSION_KEY, "Android-" + VirtualWalletApplication.getInstance().appVersion );
    params.put( RESPONSE_TYPE_KEY, "XML" );
    params.put( RESPONSE_TYPE_VERSION_KEY, "1.0" );
    params.put( RETRIEVE_POSTED_KEY, Boolean.valueOf( mRetrievePostedTransactions ).toString() );
    return params;
}
```

}

Here is where i create my request

```
 WebServiceRequest request = new WebServiceRequest(
            StringUtils.getFullServerUrlForResource("/alservlet/ValidateUserIdServlet"),
            onSuccessListener,
            onFailureListener) {

        @Override
        public void setParams(Map<String, String> params) {
            params.put("userid","mbltest6");
            params.put("mobileSaveUserId","false");
            params.put("devicePrint","Android");
        }

    };

    NetworkVolley.getInstance().sendRequest(request);
```

Comment: Actually if you get "Username not found" it means your request does not fail. It just the server fails to find the user. I would start from this encoding method which is absolutely overkill. Does it return the right parameters ? If you want to test you can just get rid of this method and enter the parametrized url directly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, the thing is, i run these requests using HttpPost and it finds the user, when I use volley, it doesn't. The only difference is that extra '&' symbol. The java code you see above is actually part of the "Request.class" file of the Volley Library. It's not mine.

Comment: In that case I would like to see the code of the Volley request. The addition of the ampersand will not destroy the request. You can try it right now adding a & at the end of the request url that works. I am also assuming the http status code is not part of the request.

Comment: Ok I have updated my post with my code. You are also correct, just tried it in a browser with an extra '&' and it did work.

Comment: Basically I'd like to see the request url which is difficult to see here especially because it's a POST. If I were you I would send a similar POST request with those parameters. If you use Firefox you can use HttpRequester addon. If it succeeds then the problem is in this code. Also, some problem can stem from small things like maybe your servlet processes GET while you send a POST.

Comment: Yeah it's definitely a code problem. The post in chrome works fine, through the app it doesn't work. I did notice that the body "Content-Types" are different though. The volley request packet shows "application/xml", the non volley one shows "text/xml". Could that be a problem?

Comment: As long as both return "Username not found" then it doesn't matter because it's a response from your server and it means it's consistent with the request parameters. I am almost ready to believe that you are not sending any parameters. You will need to debug this method `getParams` starting from the first line `setCommonParameters`. Or what if you harcode parameters APP_VERSION_KEY and RETRIEVE_POSTED_KEY ? I feel like one of these lines returns null.

Comment: Only my volley attempt returns with user not found, I checked in the packet, they're almost identical and i can see the parameters in it. There are however some minute differences. Like the "Content-Type".

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, i needed to capitalize the parameter "userId" not "userid". Keep a close eye on your parameters people!